# Finding the total quantity sold of an item X given that it is available?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have 2 tables that look like this:

```
item ID | name | available?
```

and

```
order ID | item ID | quantity
```

I want to select all the items that are available (which is a varchar yes/no) and which has sold more than 4 total quantity.

I know it has something to do with `sum` and `inner join` but I cannot get it correct. The best I've come up with is

```
SELECT i."item_id", i."name", SUM(o."quantity") 
FROM item i INNER JOIN orders o ON i."item_id" = o."item_id"
WHERE "available = yes" AND SUM(o."quantity") > 4
GROUP BY i."item_id"
```

but I get  an error

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Could anyone help me?

Comment: group by `i."item_id", i."name"`

Comment: The condition on `sum()` goes in a `having` clause.  But I can't tell if it is necessary.  Sample data and desired results would further clarify the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff e.g. return: `101 | Gulliver's Travels | 5`  where items = `101 | Gulliver's Travels | yes` and orders = `1 | 101 | 1`, `2 | 101 | 1`, `3| 101| 3`

Answer (score 1):

This query should work:

```
SELECT i.item_id, i.name, SUM(o.quantity) 
FROM item i INNER JOIN orders o ON i.item_id = o.item_id
WHERE available = "yes"
GROUP BY i.item_id,i.name
HAVING SUM(o.quantity) > 4
```

Comment: thanks for that, however it's not returning items where there has been no sale record (i.e. number sold is 0). Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Well in that case you will have to modify your order table to hold the number of items sold.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want something like this:

```
select i.item_id, i.name, sum(o.quantity)
from item i
inner join orders o on i.item_id = o.item_id
where available = 'yes'
group by i.item_id, i.name
having sum(o.quantity) > 4
```

This will give you the items with at least 4 qty on order. It doesn't mean that they are sold unless your order table holds sale information.

EDIT:

To find 3 or less items sold you could do this:

```
select i.item_id, i.name, sum(coalesce(o.quantity,0))
from item i
left join orders o on i.item_id = o.item_id
where available = 'yes'
group by i.item_id, i.name
having sum(coalesce(o.quantity,0)) < 4
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ebb7c8/1

Comment: thanks for that, however it's not returning items where there has been no sale record (i.e. number sold is 0). Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: You want items on order with 4 or more quantities, correct? Or do you want items that aren't ordered, or both?

Comment: say I want to find 3 or less items sold, how would that query be modified?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but the problem I specified is still there - items which were not ordered simply do not show up, where I expect it to show up on the result table with quantity = 0. I was thinking of an inner select which compares item id's in the orders table with the item id's in the product table, what do you think?

Comment: Added an updated. Notice `coalesce` keyword. Also included is SQLFiddle example that you can try out. `inner join` will not work for the 2nd query because `inner join` will ignore items whose record is not found in orders. `left join` will take all the items and compare as many as possible to orders without ignoring any item.